# Text written to textarea is altered when read back - CR is removed

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a `<textarea>` element in an HTML page. I am writing data to it with Javascript and want to check later if the user has altered the text at all. However if the data contains any carriage returns they appear to be silently removed, so comparing the text read from the textarea with a copy of what should be there fails.

JSFiddle here demonstrating the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/5j4erkst/

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. [The standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmltextareaelement) says:

> *the value used in the value IDL attribute ... is normalized so that line breaks use U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters.*

This differs from the value submitted to the server:

> *It is normalized so that line breaks use U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF) character pairs.*

Comment: However it also says "The element's value is defined to be the element's raw value with the textarea wrapping transformation applied." The [textarea wrapping transformation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#textarea-wrapping-transformation) should convert the newlines back to CR-NL pairs. That's not happening - the inverse transformation is happening when the string is written to the `textarea.value` property, but when reading `textarea.value` no transformation is being applied.

Comment: Yes, because the [API Value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-api-value), the IDL attribute, is the value you read from the textarea. As you can see, the quote is from the chapter, which starts with words "_For historical reasons_". The raw value represents the value internally, and that converts line-breaks to CRLFs nevertheless CR or LF only were used when the value was set.

Comment: So writing to the `value` IDL attribute writes the raw value, reading from it reads the `API value` and there is no way in Javascript to access either the raw value or the `value` value (i.e. the one referenced by `Finally, there is the value, as used in form submission and other processing models in this specification.`). Or to sum it up "For historical reasons the value attribute is broken."

Comment: I guess I'll just have to add this to the list of reasons I hate Javascript.